# Remove sub-string from string that contains questions

Tags: c#, string, substring

I want to remove all the sub-string containing a question from string.

For example,
 the original string:
 ***Hello How are you? what are you doing? this thing is perfect.***

Result: ***Hello this thing is perfect.***

I want to remove all sub-strings that start from ***what-when-where-whose-how-etc*** and ends with whether ***?(Question Mark)*** or ***.(dot)*** .

```
 Regex questions = new Regex("what|why|when|How|where|who|which|whose|whom");
 string propertyValue = "Hello How are you? what are you doing? this thing is perfect.";
 if (questions.IsMatch(propertyValue))
        {
            int index1 = propertyValue.IndexOf("what");
            int index2 = propertyValue.IndexOf('?');
            int count = index2 - index1;
            propertyValue = propertyValue.Remove(index1,count+1);

        }
```

I have tried this, but I don't understand how to get index of multiple values because I have a list of questions words.

Comment: So, what's stopping you? did you think someone will just write the code for you? Please read [ask].

Comment: use Regular Expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly straightforward:

Use a non-capturing group that looks for how/what/where etc. words: `(?:how|what|when|where|whose)`

Then any number of characters that's not a `?` or `.`, followed by either one: `'[^\?\.]*(?:\?|\.)`.

Prepend it with one or more whitespace characters to match and you should be good to go:

```
string input = "Hello How are you? what are you doing? this thing is perfect. ";
string pattern = @"\s+(?:how|what|when|where|whose)[^\?\.]*(?:\?|\.)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outputs `Hello this thing is perfect.`

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex:

```
String str = "Hello How are you? what are you doing? this thing is perfect.";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(How|What|When|Where)(.*?)(\?|\.)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
str = rgx.Replace(str, "").Replace("  ", " ");
```

The regex pattern is as follows:

Match a string starting with (`how` or `what` or etc) followed by any character and ending with `?` or `.`

The second `Replace` is to omit the extra spaces resulting from the operation..